# JS - Visual viewport returns non expected value

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, mobile

A JS SDK is running on mobile devices **inside an Android WebView**, containing **varying HTML/JS/CSS** content, collecting data. One of the parameters collected is the `visualViewport.scale`. For devices not supporting the `visualViewport` object, I've written the following method to calculate the scale and return the same value:

```
function getViewPortScale() {
    const viewportWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 1);
    const screenWidth = window.screen.width;
    return screenWidth / viewportWidth;
}
```

when running in production on some devices I get inconsistent results between the **calculated scale** and the `visualViewport.scale`. I have printed out the following information from the data collected in order to try and guess what could be the reason.

**Examples:**

---

**1)**

- viewport Scale : 0.25
- Calculated Scale : 1
- Viewport Meta Tag : `width=device-width,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1`
- User Agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; CPH1803 Build/OPM1.171019.026; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Mobile Safari/537.36 WindVane/3.0.2`

---

**2)**

- viewport Scale : 0.25
- Calculated Scale : 1
- Viewport Meta Tag : `width=device-width,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1`
- User Agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; SM-A305N Build/PPR1.180610.011; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 WindVane/3.0.2`

---

**3)**

- viewport Scale : 0.25
- Calculated Scale : 1
- Viewport Meta Tag : `width=device-width,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1`
- User Agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-G531BT Build/LMY48B; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/77.0.3865.73 Mobile Safari/537.36 WindVane/3.0.2`

---

**Q:** What could cause the `visualViewport.scale` to report `0.25` while the viewport met tag is set to `width=device-width,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1`?

Comment: Could it be related to css zoom property?

Comment: Thanks you for the reply, However, I couldn't reproduce it using CSS zoom property

Comment: Also, it looks like in Chrome at least, the measurement is taken in the innermost iframe (if any), so if your content is in an iframe, the pinch zoom isn't detected... only in the outermost window is it detected